# python methods calling in certain order

Tags: python, class, methods, properties, decorator

I often create class with some methods and execute most of its methods but in certain order so I always create last method "execute" or "run" with these methods called so I can get them executed as some other methods rely on arguments they create. Does it sound like `@property` use case?

Is there any way to define in Python which methods must be called automatically with some decorator so I can mitigate from using `execute` method ?

Simple example is below:

```
import pandas as pd


class Preprocessor:
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame([]), some_cond=False):
        assert len(df)
        assert isinstance(some_cond, bool)

        self.some_cond = some_cond
        self.df = df
        self.cols = ["col1", "col3"]

    def filter_columns(self):
        for c in self.cols:
            assert c in self.df.columns
        self.df = self.df[self.cols]

    def filter_rows(self):
        self.df = self.df[self.df["foo"] == self.some_cond]

    def execute(self):
        self.filter_columns()
        self.filter_rows()


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"foo": [True, False, True, False, True], "bar": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"]})
pp = Preprocessor(df, some_cond=True).execute()
df = pp.df
```

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd


class Preprocessor:
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame([]), some_cond=False):
        assert len(df)
        assert isinstance(some_cond, bool)

        self.some_cond = some_cond
        self.df = df
        self.cols = ["col1", "col3"]

        self.filter_columns()
        self.filter_rows()

    def filter_columns(self):
        for c in self.cols:
            assert c in self.df.columns
        self.df = self.df[self.cols]

    def filter_rows(self):
        self.df = self.df[self.df["foo"] == self.some_cond]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"foo": [True, False, True, False, True], "bar": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"]})
df = Preprocessor(df, some_cond=True).df
```

So something more like on entry and on exit behaviour.

Comment: Why not call `execute` in `__init__` unless you want to "execute" after the initalization some time, so do you want that?

Comment: I do not call the module directly. I have more than one class spreaded accross few modules and I create main module with classess imports where I instantiate classes and set objects in some kind of pipeline to execute. Very often more than one class is built in such way as desribed in the Q.

Comment: if you had your choice can you show how it would look ideally to you?  Do you want something like df = Preprocessor(df, some_cond=True)?

Comment: please see my edit. the problem is what if i have 5 methods?

Comment: So instead of 5 lines in your `__init__` you want to add a decorator to every method (also 5 lines). What do you gain by that?

Comment: Good point. Would you keep methods execution in __init__ or create separate method execute()? The advantage I see of having execute method is that I can create method, I can call its methods separately or just call execute to call all methods in right order.